# Plist serialisation in Iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have an IPhone  application in which i am using this code .

```
NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;
NSDictionary *payloadDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization 
                       propertyListWithData:subscriptionProduct.receipt 
                                    options:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                     format:&plistFormat 
                                       error:nil];
```

where i am getting the subscriptionProduct.receipt  correctly and reciept is an nsdata, which is declared inside the subscriptionProduct class.But after the conversion when i am trying to print payloadDict it is terned to be null.can anybody help me

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the error out of the method and displaying it:

```
NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;
NSError *parseError;
NSDictionary *payloadDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization 
                       propertyListWithData:subscriptionProduct.receipt 
                                    options:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                     format:&plistFormat 
                                      error:&parseError]; 

NSLog(@"payloadDict = %@", payloadDict);
NSLog(@"parseError = %@", parseError);
```

If `parseError` is `nil`, the property list serialization *thinks* it read the data properly.  If not, its contents should tell you where to look.

Comment: (Unexpected character { at line 1) UserInfo=0xf432760 {NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character { at line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)} this is the error how i can remove this

Comment: The error tells us that `receipt` has some content, but from the very beginning (line 1), it is not formatted like a property list file.  How is `receipt` created?  Does it come from `dataFromPropertyList` or `dataWithPropertyList`?

Comment: reciept was of type nsdata.and here i am trying make it in to a plist format by using the above code,then the error comes

Comment: That's odd.  Are you trying to _decode_ the `receipt` so that you can read its contents, or are you trying to _store_ it in a larger block of data for later retrieval?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do.  Are you reading from files or are you writing to files?

Comment: I want to take that data as a plist and takes the values corresponding to some tags  NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:[payloadDict objectForKey:@"purchase-info"]];

Answer (score 0):

Your comments seem to say that you want to construct a new `NSDictionary` that stores the object `subscriptionProduct.receipt`.

You can do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *payloadDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

// Always check if values are nil before adding them to a dictionary.
if (subscriptionProduct.receipt)
    [payloadDict setObject:subscriptionProduct.receipt forKey:@"receipt"];
```

If you want to load the receipt later, you can do this:

```
NSData *receiptData = [payloadDict objectForKey:@"receipt"];
```